# Error in rounding off values using .round in Ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point, rounding

The following piece of code works perfectly in script/console but returns the following error when i compile the same in a ruby script.:

```
:in `round': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

tf={"ph"=>{0=>1.33333333333333, 1=>1.5}, "fee"=>{0=>1.66666666666667}, "test"=>{0=>1.16666666666667, 1=>1.25}, "what"=>{0=>2.0, 1=>2.0}, "for"=>{0=>1.5}, "is"=>{0=>1.83333333333333, 1=>1.75}}

tf.each{|k,v| v.each{|k1,v1| tf[k][k1]=(v1.round(5))}}
```

Any Ideas ? Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Float#round` seems to work differently in [Ruby 1.8](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Float.html#M000244) and [Ruby 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Float.html#M000532): in 1.8 it complains about the given argument, in 1.9 returns back float properly rounded to the given number of decimals.

But, as the [article](http://solutions.hans-eric.com/rounding-off-floating-point-numbers-in-ruby) linked in the other answer wisely says:

> you should consider the reason you’re
>   performing the rounding (or
>   equivalent) operation. If it’s for
>   presentation reasons only a better way
>   might be to use a format string
>   instead, and leave the original data
>   intact.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you are not supposed to pass an argument to the round method. You have passed 5 to it. 
If you are trying to round it to 5 decimal places, there is no builtin method for that (that I'm aware of). This is a page that explains how to do so: http://solutions.hans-eric.com/rounding-off-floating-point-numbers-in-ruby

Comment: I need to round off each number to 5 decimal places. And interestingly the same piece of code WORKS in the console !

Comment: That is interesting. I've edited to include a link that will help you.