# "wrong number of arguments" ArgumentError when using round

Tags: ruby, rounding

I am trying to convert a temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius:

```
puts 'Convertir grados Fahrenheit a Celcius'
STDOUT.flush
x = gets.chomp

aprox = (x * 100.0).round(2) / 100.0

resultado = (aprox-32)/1.8

puts resultado
```

I use the correct formula for converting Fahrenheit to Celcius:

> Celsius = Fahrenheit - 32 / 1.8

However, when I run this in the console, it gives me the following error:

> `round': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

I've tried different things but I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748911/error-in-rounding-off-values-using-round-in-ruby

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ruby version prior to 1.9.0 `round` does not take arguments. It rounds to the nearest integer (see the [documentation about floats and the use of round](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Float.html#M000244))

Use this instead:

```
aprox = (x * 100).round() / 100.0
```

The whole point of multiplying and dividing by 100 is to round the last two digit of x.

Comment: You should divide by 100.0 at the end. Otherwise you're performing integer division and just losing the last two digits.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I want to give you a vote, but I can't, sorry.

Comment: sepp2k Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the code. I've also added a precision based on Greg answer.

Answer (score 5):

You don't specify what version of Ruby you are using. That makes a difference, because in Rubies prior to 1.9 Float#round did not take a parameter. In 1.9+ it does.

```
>> RUBY_VERSION #=> "1.9.2"
>> pi = 3.141 #=> 3.141
>> pi.round #=> 3
>> pi.round(1) #=> 3.1
>> 3.141.round(1) #=> 3.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I don't know this and it's interesting.

Answer (score 2):

activesupport (part of rails) also gives you Float#round(precision)

Comment: Note that activesupport can be used outside rails. It can even be usefull for non-web ruby apps.